# Rspec Validation Tests for Date and Boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, validation, rspec, tdd

I want to re-write two custom `validation tests`, one for `Dates` and one for `Boolean values` without having to use the custom methods that I've created. Is there a shorthand way to validate Date or Boolean values (as being of those type) using `shoulda-matchers` or `valid-attribute` gems?

I would like to steer away from having to use another gem if possible. I have not included my code because I'm not looking for a custom re-write, just shorthand generic validation syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted way to validate a boolean field is:

```
validates :field, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
```

I don't know if there is as much consensus on validating dates, but I'm aware of the following gem options:

- https://github.com/codegram/date_validator
- https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness

although both of these only claim support through Rails 3.

A custom Rails 4 solution is described in http://andowebsit.es/blog/noteslog.com/post/how-to-validate-dates-in-rails-4/